# show 2 items per row[react native]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am learning react native and in all the tutorials i see ListView has been used with only 1 items per row. I have not used ListView, though. I have only 6 items that has to be shown as flat grid with 2 items per row and should be responsive. I know its a basic question, but i have tried from my side too which can be seen in the image

[image]

This is my code

```
 renderDeviceEventList() {
    return _.map(this.props.deviceEventOptions, deviceEventOption => (
        <View key={deviceEventOption.id}>
            <Icon
                name={deviceEventOption.icon_name}
                color="#ddd"
                size={30}
                onPress={() =>
                    this.props.selectDeviceEvent(deviceEventOption)
                }
            />
            <Text style={{ color: "#ff4c4c" }}>
                {deviceEventOption.icon_name}
            </Text>
        </View>
    ));
}
render() {
    return (
        <View
            style={{
                flex: 1,
                top: 60,
                flexDirection: "row",
                justifyContent: "space-around",
                flexWrap: "wrap",
                marginBottom: 10
            }}
        >
            {this.renderDeviceEventList()}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: When i give width and height to View component inside renderDeviceEventList, it works but is not responsive. I know there is a Dimension library but i have heard it wont work when changing the orientation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To make a 2 row grid using `ListView` you could use this code as an example:

```
renderGridItem( item ){
    return (<TouchableOpacity style={styles.gridItem}>
        <View style={[styles.gridItemImage, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}]}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:25, color:'white'}}>
                {item.fields.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}
            </Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.gridItemText}>{item.fields.name}</Text> 
    </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}

renderCategories(){

    var listItems = this.dsinit.cloneWithRows(this.state.dataSource);

    return (
        <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: '#E8E8E8', flex: 1}} >
            <ListView 
                contentContainerStyle={styles.grid}
                dataSource={listItems}
                renderRow={(item) => this.renderGridItem(item)}
            />
        </ScrollView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    grid: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        flex: 1,
    },
    gridItem: {
        margin:5,
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    gridItemImage: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        borderWidth: 1.5, 
        borderColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: 50,
    },
    gridItemText: {
        marginTop: 5,
        textAlign:'center',
    },
});
```

Change styles to choose how many rows you want to see on screen. This code is responsive.

Comment: I don't think you need that `ScrollView` there. Do you?

Comment: Even though this works on most mobile devices, I don't think this is the best solution. Because with this approach, you assume that the width of screen is less than ~450. This might be true at this moment but later, it can be not true. @nikk-wong's answer is the correct way I guess.

Answer (score 51):

The correct way to do it would be with `flexBasis`, with a value set to `(1/n)%` where `n` is the desired # of rows > 0. For two rows:

```
.parent {
    flex: 1,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexDirection: 'row'
}
.child {
    flexBasis: '50%'
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you - minor typo in parent 'flexDirecton', easy enough to fix, but broke the copy-pasteability :) Upvoting and big thanks.

Comment: nice, thank you (just make sure the values, such as 'wrap' and 'row' are in single quotes, otherwise react native will throw an error

Comment: The property for Flex direction has typo, please update it like this: `flexDirection`

Answer (score 32):

You can try the flat list from react native.
where in you can specific the number of columns and also can mention the vertical direction or horizontal direction.
Sample code:

```
<FlatList
data={this.props.data}
keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}     //has to be unique   
renderItem={this._renderItem} //method to render the data in the way you want using styling u need
horizontal={false}
numColumns={2}
          />
```

Refer https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html for more.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to make the grid view trully responsive about the device width import **Dimesions**:

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  ...
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
```

And change the **gridItem** width for this:

```
gridItem: {
  margin: 5,
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2.2, //Device width divided in almost a half
  height: 150,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
},
```

Also you can change the image width to be the same or less as the **gridItem**.

Comment: much better than setting an arbitrary number like 150, because you wont get the same result on devices with hight dpis/ratios. Great answer! Its better, but you would have to check for pixel ratios as well since it wont scale properly on android.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a FlatList and set to it the `numColumns={2}` prop and `style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}`. 
In my case I'm working with 3 cols: 
[FlatList with `numColumns={3}`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnzA8.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
flex: 1,
flexDirection: 'row',
justifyContent: 'space-between'
```

Try to put this!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).