# Render image like searchScreen in Instagram

Tags: react-native

I wanted to render images from db like Instagram searchScreen

```
class FeedHome extends Component {
    _renderItem = ({ item }) => <PicsContent {...item} />

    render() {

    return(
      <Root>
        <FlatList
          contentContainerStyle={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
          data={data.getPosts}
          keyExtractor={item => item._id}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
        />
     </Root>
   );
 }
}
```

and this is PicsContent function;

```
function PicsContent({image}) {
  return (
    <Root>
      <PicsContentContainer>
        {image}
      </PicsContentContainer>
      <PicsContentContainer>
        {image}
      </PicsContentContainer>
      <PicsContentContainer>
        {image}
      </PicsContentContainer>
   </Root>
  )
}
```

I put the result of these code are in the link below.

Comment: this is image links: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSwqF.png)[link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the FlatList items in 3 columns like instagram search, you can use the property `numColumns={3}`.

[You can see this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47027729/6673819)

Comment: I'm glad that my answer had helped you! Mark it with +1, pls ;)